# How to add data to list dynamical in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, list, extjs, dynamic, touch

I'm new to Sencha Touch and I'm trying to build an app (no web app but native with PhoneGap) containing a list that should add items with click on button.
I was searching for days but can't find any helpful solution.

How do I have to change my code that I don't have to put hard coded values into my

```
data:[]
```

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Note', { 

extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: ['MyApp.model.Note'],

config: {
model: 'MyApp.model.Note',

data:
[   
{id: 1, content: 'Blog 1', categoryid: 1, category: 'Nonsense' },
{id: 2, content: 'Blog 2', categoryid: 1, category: 'Nonsense' },
{id: 3, content: 'Blog 3', categoryid: 2, category: 'Food' }
],
}
});
```

I'm creating my list

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.NoteList',{
extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
xtype: 'notelist',
config: {

    store: "Note", //will create the store later


    itemTpl: [
        '<div>',
        '    <div>{content}</div>',
        '    <p>{category}</p>',
        '</div>'
    ],
    onItemDisclosure: function(record,btn,index) {
        this.push(Ext.create('MyApp.view.RegisterPanel'));
        //when the little arrow on the right is tapped
    }
},
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add items to your store instance.

Example:

```
var myStore = Ext.create('MyApp.store.Note');

//Use add with a config object
myStore.add({
   //your record here
   id: 1,
   content: "Blog 1",
   categoryid: 1,
   category: "Nonsense"
});

//Or create an instance of your record
var myRecord = Ext.create('MyApp.model.Note', {
   id: 1,
   content: "Blog 3",
   categoryid: 2,
   category: "Food"
});

//Add the record to the store
myStore.add(myRecord);
```

Comment: thanks, where do I have to put those?
At the moment i create a list and add the store like this:
 store: "Note",

Comment: You can use the `getStore()` function of your list when you click the button and then add your records there.

Comment: thanks a lot.. so easy. Haven't been thinking about that.. :)